# C++ how to skip next 2 iterations of loop i.e. multiple continue

Tags: c++

Say I have the following loop:

```
vector <string> args;
for (string s : args)
{
    if ( s == "condition" )
        continue; // skips to next iteration
}
```

How can I skip multiple iterations in this instance? Is there something like multiple continue statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `for` loop with index:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < args.size(); i++)
{
    if (args[i] == "condition") {
        i++;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better way than iterators

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterator.

```
auto it_end = --args.end();
for(auto it = args.begin(); it != args.end(); it++){
    if ( *it == "condition" && it != it_end) it++;
}
```

Comment: If `"condition"` is at the end of `args` then this will cause an error because `it++` is called once more when `it` is at `args.end()`

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think now it's correct and doesn't lost much efficiency.@tntxtnt

Comment: If `args` is empty, the `--args.end()` looks like undefined behavior to me.

Comment: What's the benefit of using iterator in such "ugly" and unsafe condition, instead of using index based for loop?

Comment: I didn't think it through at first, so after some fixes, the code become ugly. Actually, I think your way is better.@MartinZhai